# Microsoft Access - Form list box to filter report for one to many relationship values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have three tables; Applications, Regions, and ApplicationRegionJoin. An application can have many regions via the join table, which stores just the ApplicationID and RegionID. I have a query that pulls all applications onto a report and a form on which the user can enter filter parameters for running the report via a command button. I can successfully use a multi select list box to filter based on a value on Applications but I'm stuck on how to use a list box to filter based on region(s). Is this possible?

EDIT: Here is my current VBA code for filtering based on two separate columns in Applications using two separate multiselect listboxes. I'm relatively new to VBA so please excuse the lack of DRYness or any other lack of best practice etc.

```
Private Sub RunApplicationReport_Click()

    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Application Report"

    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim varItem As Variant

    strWhere = vbNullString

    If Me.listStatuses.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
        If strWhere <> vbNullString Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
        'add selected values to string
        Set ctl = Me.listStatuses
        For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
        str = str & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
        Next varItem
        'trim trailing comma
        str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
        'open the report, restricted to the selected items
        strWhere = strWhere & "BidStatuses.BidStatus IN(" & str & ")"
    End If
    If Me.listCategories.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
        If strWhere <> vbNullString Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
        'add selected values to string
        Set ctl = Me.listCategories
        For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
        str = str & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
        Next varItem
        'trim trailing comma
        str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
        'open the report, restricted to the selected items
        strWhere = strWhere & "Categories.Category IN(" & str & ")"
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenReport ("Application Report"), acViewPreview, , strWhere

End Sub
```

Comment: They would be 2 halves of a WHERE clause.  You would use it the same way you use the filter for Applications.  You would probably have to build the SQL in VBA, so it can account for a selection of "All" by using an If/Then statement.

Comment: @JohnnyBones That's what I was thinking but I just can't seem to get it to work, nor have I been able to find an example online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I came up with for a solution. Basically it builds a comma delimited string of the selected region names from the form listbox (similar to the other listbox code from above) and then creates a recordset of the ApplicationIDs from the join table where the RegionID equals the ID from the Regions table where the Region name equals a value in that string. Then the report where clause is updated to filter for matching ApplicationIDs.

```
If Me.listRegions.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then

        Dim regs As String
        regs = vbNullString
        Set ctl = Me.listRegions
        For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
            regs = regs & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
        Next varItem
        regs = Left(regs, Len(regs) - 1)

        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ApplicationID FROM ApplicationRegionJoin WHERE RegionID IN(" & _
        "SELECT ID FROM Regions WHERE Region IN(" & regs & "))") 'because listRegions is bound to Region (the region name) not the ID from Regions

        Dim apps As String
        apps = vbNullString

        If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            Do Until rs.EOF = True
                apps = apps & rs!ApplicationID & ","
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop

            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing

        End If

        If strWhere <> vbNullString Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
        strWhere = strWhere & "Applications.ID IN(" & apps & ")"

    End If
```